# Inductive reasoning question

Tags: contest-math, pattern-recognition

Can someone help with this inductive reasoning question. What should come next in this series of 5 and what is the reasoning?

[image]

Can someone also help with the following question.

[image]

Comment: b is the answer.

Comment: What is your reasoning?

Comment: 1st->shift black ->bigger other ->white ->1st ->shift black..@user13892

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $D$.

In 1-3, solid squares go small, small, big in the bottom left.  In 2-6, empty squares repeat the pattern by going small, small, big (top left instead).

In 1-3, triangles at the top go empty right, full left, full left.  In 2-6 the pattern is repeated (at the bottom instead): empty right, full left, full left.

So square 6 has a big empty square top left and full triangle bottom left.

Re question 2, the answer is $C$.

The big circle goes black, white, black white, so black white again would make sense.  The dot is in 3 small grey triangles, so makes sense it would then be in 3 small white ones.

Finally, ignoring the orientation of the hexagon, the dot rotates one triangle clockwise around the hexagon each step so it should end up a fraction anticlockwise of one end in step 6.

Comment: Hi Robert, can you also help with this second question (see edited question above).

Comment: These are pretty tricky. Can you not ask another question? I need the points!

Comment: The big circle goes black, white, black white, so black white again would make sense.  The dot is in 3 small grey triangles, so makes sense it would then be in 3 small white ones. The dot rotates one triangle clockwise around the hexagon each step so it should end up a fraction anticlockwise of one end.  I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say D because of the symmetry of the situation and because the first square has colours different --> the corresponding 3rd square has equal colours, the 2nd has equal colours --> corresponding 4th square has different colors, therefore the missing square must have different colours.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer have defined the logic of 1st question quite well.

For the second question, if we take the alternative occurrence of black and white colour in ellipse then it would eliminate other options except A, B and E.

Also, we can easily observe that:

1. Dot had been changing its position by one place in clockwise manner
   in every step in the consisting six triangles of hexagon.
2. The color of the hexagon's triangles are also changing alternatively while maintaining the opposite triangles in same shade or white space.

Combining the above points will elimate the other options except A.

Hence, A will be the answer.